# string starting from `08` is read as null instead of correct value when send via post

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have ASP.NET WebAPI project (not .net core) I've added a simple endpoint that is accepting a POST request.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("cases/{caseId:int}/confirm")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ConfirmCase(int caseId, [FromBody] string code)
{
   //
}
```

When I'm doing a sample request with `0012` as body:
[image]

then inside my method, I see the value is read correctly:
[image]

but when I do a request with `0008` as body:

[image]

I get null as `code`:
[image]

my workaround is to send code inside quotes like this: `"0008"`, then everything works as expected.

I wasn't able to find any explanation why this behaves like this, why the body needs a quote around and why only for value starting with `08`.

Comment: Have you got anything in there which might be interpreting the body as json? A workaround of putting it in quotes (and then the quotes being removed by the time that `code` is assigned) stinks of it being processed as json (although I'm not sure why that would cause `0012` to succeed but `0008` to fail, although I've got a hunch that octal might be involved?). See here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sV4QeF

Comment: @canton7 that's what I'm using as a workaround :), but this doesn't leave me alone - why this works like this. I've created a new project using VS, no middlewares, nothing that might process the request.

Comment: In octal 8 is an invalid digit only 0-7 are allowed. The interesting is that it tries to convert to int..

Comment: [This article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/dec/13/accepting-raw-request-body-content-with-aspnet-web-api#[FromBody]-to-retrieve-Content) says "*`[FromBody]` works for properly formatted content – ie. JSON, XML and whatever other media formatters that are configured in the Conneg pipeline. But [FromBody] still doesn’t work if you just want to capture the entire raw content – so if the data is not JSON or XML encoded and you just want the raw data [FromBody] is no help.*". It says to use `await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` to get the raw body without interpreting it as json

Comment: @PawełŁukasik The other interesting thing is that it turns the int back into a string, but formats it as an octal number (`0012` parses as `10`, but is rendered back as the string `0012`)

Comment: What happens if you set the data type as "Text" rather than JSON? Maybe the parser doesn't consider it valid unless there are opening and closing braces or something?

Comment: @CraigH I get the same results. I've created a custom binder and attribute according to [this article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/dec/13/accepting-raw-request-body-content-with-aspnet-web-api#%5BFromBody%5D-to-retrieve-Content)

Comment: @canton7 thanks for the link! I've created a custom attribute and binder based on code from your link. Works great!